# Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Добрый вечер!

Никак не могу понять, почему не проходят тесты, выполняет первый редирект, а не второй, как описанно к контроллере, сам код работает корректно, редиректы происходят именно так как описано.

Rspec 3.5.1

Rails 5

Ruby 2.3.1

Код контроллера:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  private

...
```

---

```
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

Тест:

```
    describe "as wrong user" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
        before { log_in user, no_capybara: true }

        describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
            before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
            specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
            specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
        end

        describe "submitting a PATCH request to the User#update action" do
            before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
            specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
```

Тест ошибки:

```
    Failures:
```

1) AuthenticationPages autorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action should redirect to "http://www.example.com/"
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }

```
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/login>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/login".
```

Comment: Что за `current_user?(@user)`? Откуда хелпер?

Comment: @D-side Из sessions, выглядит она так `def currnet user?(user) user == current_user end`

Comment: А что за `logged_in?`? И что вы вообще для аутентификации используете?